# Attiny88 programming with Arduino

Tags: attiny, isp

I want to program Attiny88 with Arduino IDE 1.6.5. I chose Attiny88  because it's the cheapest Attiny (as low as $0.5) and at the same time has 28 pins. I found a library that support Attiny88 (https://github.com/TCWORLD/ATTinyCore) but it seams it does not support IDE 1.6.5 and generates errors when I burn bootloader or during ISP.

Is there any library to program Attiny88 with Arduino 1.6.5?

Comment: The older versions of Arduino are still available for download. Why not use an older version?

Answer (score 2):

Finally I found ATTinyCore library. I have tested it with a blink sketch. Just download the zip file. Unzip and copy  Attinycore-master directory into "program files/Arduino/hardware/arduino/avr" directory. Restart the IDEA. Select ATTiny x8 Series from the boards menu, and select the specific chip (48 or 88), clock speed, and BOD level from the appropriate menus that will appear in the tools menu after selecting ATTiny x8 series as the board.

https://github.com/SpenceKonde/ATTinyCore

Answer (score 1):

I went through the same problem finding the cores for the attiny 88 and found this

http://forum.arduino.cc/index.php?topic=320742.0

[programming attiny88 & attiny828 with arduino](https://arduino.stackexchange.com/questions/13011/programming-attiny88-attiny828-with-arduino)

However, I have not yet found the core for the attiny88 at 12mhz (http://co.mouser.com/ProductDetail/Atmel/ATTINY88-AU/?qs=sGAEpiMZZMvqv2n3s2xjscfa4zIkTHJI8r77%252bczQD%252bE%3d)

Comment: Different speeds don't use different cores. Simply copy the existing entry in boards.txt and modify the clock rate there.

Comment: The above links don't lead to a working core. The bootloader does not work correctly.