# programming attiny88 & attiny828 with arduino

Tags: attiny

I found some information that the attiny88 and attiny828 can be programed from an arduino, similar to the programing of the attiny85/45, simply connecting the right pins. https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/98970/how-to-program-atmel-attiny88-not-45-or-85

However, what I have not been able to find out are the arduino cores (drivers) for the attiny88 and attiny828.
I wonder if the cores (or drivers) to program the attiny88 and attiny828 from an arduino are available somewhere or would they have to be constructed?.

Comment: I have never come across cores for them (not that I've been specifically looking for them though).

Comment: 88 support seems to exist. See http://arduino.stackexchange.com/questions/12977/attiny88-programming-with-arduino

Comment: I would suggest you look into getting a real programmer. As @Gerben says there seems to be support for it, but if you buy an Atmel Programmer or a 3rd party programmer, you will make your life easier. If you plan on doing AVR programming you will eventually graduate from Arduino. There are a number of programmers that can program the ATTiny 88. http://www.atmel.com/tools/STK500.aspx?tab=devices.